# Jackson/ObjectMapper: Expression Language Injection and "${...}"

Tags: spring, jackson

I am attempting to solve a vulnerability during deserialization that shows scripts can be run within a JSON string field when presented as in this example:

```
{
  "field":"ABC ${ 'a'.getClass().forName('javax.script.ScriptEngineManager').<get OS information>}"
}
```

Questions:

1. What is this feature, intended or otherwise?
2. Can I explicitly disable it?

Comment: Looks like [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)

Comment: Why by default would SpEL be allowed to be accessed like this? Not saying you're wrong, but that would just never occur to me.

Comment: Joe, can you share a demo application ([MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) which exhibits this problem/feature? I tried with an empty application of <https://start.spring.io> and I could not reproduce the mentioned behavior with default settings

Comment: I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68003925/what-is-this-hacker-trying-to-do-with-this-java-code#68004253) with an answer mentioning a vulnerability in Struts 2.