# What is this hacker trying to do with this Java code?

Tags: java, url

In my server log of my web server, I've noticed a hacker trying this:

```
https://[domain name]/index.action?action:${%23a%3d(new%20java.lang.processbuilder(new%20java.lang.string[]{'sh','-c','id'})).start(),%23b%3d%23a.getinputstream(),%23c%3dnew%20java.io.inputstreamreader(%23b),%23d%3dnew%20java.io.bufferedreader(%23c),%23e%3dnew%20char[50000],%23d.read(%23e),%23matt%3d%23context.get(%27com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.httpservletresponse%27),%23matt.getwriter().println(%23e),%23matt.getwriter().flush(),%23matt.getwriter().close()}
```

Which URL decodes to this:

```
https://[domain name]/index.action?action:${#a=(new java.lang.processbuilder(new java.lang.string[]{'sh','-c','id'})).start(),#b=#a.getinputstream(),#c=new java.io.inputstreamreader(#b),#d=new java.io.bufferedreader(#c),#e=new char[50000],#d.read(#e),#matt=#context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.httpservletresponse'),#matt.getwriter().println(#e),#matt.getwriter().flush(),#matt.getwriter().close()}
```

My server doesn't use Java but I'm trying to understand what this hacker is trying to do here and why this could be a vulnerability. After all, I'm not just a developer but also need to know about how to protect a server, including servers not set up by me.

Code seems to start a new process and then tries to read data from the input stream. I'm assuming this is the input stream of the current web session.

As this attack is also tried over /login.action and various other URL's and different Java code, I am considering it to be potential dangerous. But I can't explain why this is dangerous.

The specific domain is under attack right now as the hacker tries to see if it's running WordPress or Magenta or other known systems and also tries several different attacks.

But what matters is this: the domain is currently under development and the owner still has to decide which development tools will be used. The choices are between Java and ASP-NET so is this attack dangerous if he chooses to pick Java?

Comment: Call `id` (that prints the known local OS users and their user ids) on your shell and write the results to a web address, but the address isn't written there. There must be something else defining `#context` (or `%23context`).

Comment: I'm not even sure that attempt at code injection would normally work given that stuff like `String` is written all-lower case. So it looks like they're trying to reproduce some probably known vulnerability of some badly-written piece of code that accepted badly formatted java code and ran it no questions asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's trying to exploit a RCE vulnerability in Struts 2, I think [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/S2-053) one. A bad one, Freemarker would execute any code inside `${}` tags.

The **Freemarker code** starts a process to execute `id` to see if the server is running as `root`, giving full access to the box. Even a vulnerable Struts version might not be too bad here, since the attacker might not be interested unless you were `root`.

The attacker's program has a lot of these old vulnerabilities that would work on very unsafe servers, but even simple admin protocol will protect against these amateur attacks. You would only be vulnerable when running as root, using an old version of a software, opening up your db server to the internet with a weak or default password, etc.

Regardless of the technology you choose, there will be security issues and you need to follow the CVEs. For example a modern Java framework like [Spring](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=Spring) has a few, but remote code execution is quite rare, and that's what those attack programs look for.

Comment: I know about security, which is why I do additional URL logging to see what gets called.  Good to know it's related to Apache, as the owner doesn't want to use that.

Comment: I assume you mean the owner doesn't want to use Apache [httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/), but that has nothing to do with Struts also being an Apache project.

Comment: No, the owner just doesn't want anything made by Apache. Not sure why, as I don't want to question that decision. "No Apache software" is a clear work instruction for me. :)